# GoDaddy Domain redirect to Force.com Site problem

Tags: force.com-sites

I have created a force.com site and added a simple Hello World VF page to the site. I have a personal domain URL that I would like to point to the Force.com site. Below are the steps I followed but am not able to get it working. Can someone point me to the right steps for this.

1. Force.com site -> sdo-demo-main-1452de9b273-145750e5859.force.com/allpets [Works]
2. GoDaddy domain -> www.allpets.in [Does not redirect to above url]

**Go Daddy Changes** - Changed cname for www to sdo-demo-main-1452de9b273-145750e5859.force.com

**Salesforce Changes** - Added custom domain (the long one) and create a force.com site pointing to the long custom domain/allpets

Am I missing some step coz I am expecting that the redirect from GoDaddy go directly to the Force.com Site but it is not happening.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have set up the redirect you have to wait for it to propagate to the many, many DNS servers on the internet.  DNS entries have a Time To Live (TTL) setting that dictates when the server will refresh its cache.  This can take up to 24 hours.

I've checked the DNS for www.allpets.in and that is now correctly pointing at a Force.com sites server (e2227.b.akameiedge.net/23.74.121.54).  If I access the Force.com site directly it looks exactly the same as www.allpets.in, so I'd say that DNS propagation has taken place for the DNS servers in my part of the world (nice pictures on the site BTW).

If you are still seeing what you consider to be old pages, try clearing your browser cache, as pages are often cached there for up to 24 hours as well.

If you want to read more on what happens when DNS is changed, take a look at :

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/domain-names/dns-nameserver-changes/domain-names-dns-changes